# Querying if a user is a member of a group

Tags: delphi, active-directory, ldap, ado, delphi-2006

I have no experience with Active Directory.

I am using Delphi to develop an application which interacts with Active Directory. I need to know the best way to test whether an Active Directory user belongs to a specified group. How do I do that?

I'm using Delphi 2006 BDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take nested groups into account, the easiest way is to use the [tokenGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute that contains a (computed) array of SID's (including nested groups). From there you can either convert this list of sids to names (by feeding it to [DsCrackNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675970%28VS.85%29.aspx)) or get the SID from the group you wish to check and compare sids ([EqualSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to share you [NLDNetAPI.pas](https://github.com/NLDelphi/NLDUtils/blob/main/NLDNetAPI.pas).

Having no extensive experience with active directory and not being in the possession of a Delphi version above 7, I do suppose that you could obtain all the users from a particular group with the following code:

```
GetNetGroupUsers([ServerName], [GroupName], [StringList not nil], False, True);
```

Explore that StringList for your UserName.

Comment: It runs perfect! Thx